# Vue.js global event bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a global event bus so that two sibling components can communicate with each other. I have searched around; however, I cannot find any examples of how to implement one. This is what I have so far:

```
var bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('Increment', {
  template: "#inc",
  data: function() {
   return ({count: 0})
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function(){
      var increment = this.count++
      bus.$emit('inc', increment)
  }
 }
})

Vue.component('Display', {
  template: "#display",
  data: function(){
  return({count: 0})
  },
 created: function(){
   bus.$on('inc', function(num){
   alert(num)
   this.count = num;
  });
 }
})


vm = new Vue({
 el: "#example",
})
```

I created my templates like so: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/PzpZBg

I'd like the `Increment` component to communicate the count to the `Display` component. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in `bus.$on()`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The problem is that within your `bus.$on` function, `this` refers to the bus.  You just need to bind the current Vue instance to that function using `.bind()`:

```
bus.$on('inc', function(num){
 alert(num)
 this.count = num;
}.bind(this));
```

You should also check out https://github.com/vuejs/vuex if you want to manage global application states.

EDIT: Since this page seems to get a lot of clicks I want to edit and add another method, per ChristopheMarois in the comments:

EDIT: In effort to make this answer a little clearer, and so future readers don't need to read comments here's what's happening:

Using a fat arrow like below binds the lexical scope of 'this' to the component instead of to the event bus.

```
bus.$on('inc', (num) => {
 alert(num);
 this.count = num;
});
```

Or removing the alert:

```
bus.$on('inc', (num) => this.count = num);
```

Comment: Hmm. It still doesn't work. Not too sure what is going on as I've never tried to create an event bus before. I have implemented this same program in vuex. Just that in the recent vuejs 2 guide, Evan mentions the possibility of using an event bus for easy problems

Comment: A bug may be that you're post-incrementing count with `var increment = this.count++;`. Change it to `var increment = ++this.count;`. That way `count` is incremented before being assigned to `increment`

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty confused on how to create this.

Comment: @aidma. Good catch. I was wondering why I had to click it twice before it incremented from 0 to 1.

Comment: @Jeff - I had the same problem as the OP and the ".bind(this)" part solved it. Upvoting and hopefully my comment will help future people with the same problem. The Vue documentation is way too light when it comes to the eventing parts.

Comment: vuex is a solid choice

Comment: Another solution is to use arrow functions (that auto-binds the same-scope lexical `this`) like `bus.$on('inc', num => this.count = num)`

Comment: thanks @ChristopheMarois I added the arrow function version since this page seems to get a lot of views

Comment: You can have a look at the tutorial I wrote. http://thewebjuice.com/vue-todo-list-delete-option-global-event-bus-part-ii/

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, although I have everything correct (this binding / arrow function). The only difference is that the eventbus and the components are in different files, but surely that shouldn't make a difference?

Comment: Heads up, if you are using .bind(this) when subscribing to an event and you want to unsubscribe (and you probably should) you will need to assign the bounded function to a variable and use this on both the $on and $off.

Answer (score 4):

As you write ES5 JavaScript you have to be aware of the fact that what you refer to by using the `this` keyword might change, according to the scope, it is called from.

A useful metaphor to get your head around the `this` concept is to think of the curly braces in ES5 as fences, that contain/bind its own `this`.

When you use `this` in the callback function of your event bus, `this` does not refer to your Vue component, but the *bus* object, which has no *count* data, so the data you expect to update doesn't.

If you have/want to write ES5 syntax a common workaround (besides binding `this` as suggested by the accepted answer) is to assign the `this` keyword to a variable like so:

```
created: function(){
  var self = this;
  bus.$on('inc', function(num){
    alert(num)
    self.count = num;
  });
}
```

If you can write ES6, do so whenever possible. You can always compile/transpile down to ES5 with [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel). The accepted answer shows you how by using arrow functions.

Arrow functions work in that case because they do not bind their own `this`.

To stick with the fence metaphor: imagine the ES6 arrow poking a hole in your function fence, so the outer `this` can pass through and you can call `this` as intended.

To learn more about ES6 arrow functions visit:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: this is the only answer that worked, think due to ES6 strict mode var self = this; is essential otherwise an error is thrown

Answer (score 3):

This is answered long back, here is my solution using in vue.js-2

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

export const eventBus = new Vue({
  methods:{
    counter(num) {
      this.$emit('addNum', num);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
});
```

**comp1.vue**

```
//Calling my named export
import { eventBus } from '../../main'
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ count }}</h1>
    <button @click="counterFn">Counter</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { eventBus } from '../../main'

  export default {
    name: 'comp-one',
    data() {
      return {
        count: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      counterFn() {
        eventBus.counter(this.count);
      }
    },
    created() {
      eventBus.$on('addNum', () => {
        this.count++;
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: it's better to not have methods in `EventBus` because it's global and will break encapsulation in this case. Just use `emit` and `on` with empty `EventBus` vue instance. That's all.

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev I agree with you, and these days I am doing just like what you said.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Assume Vue.js 2.

Create a reusable Event-Bus component and attach it to `Vue` via plugin pattern:

```
// ./components/EventBus.vue
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()

// ./plugins/EventBus.js
export default {
  install(Vue) {
    const { EventBus } = require('../components/EventBus')
    Vue.prototype.$bus = EventBus
  }
}

// ./main.js
import EventBus from './plugins/EventBus'
Vue.use(EventBus)
```

Then, you can do anywhere in your code:
`this.$bus.$emit('some-event', payload)`

As a side note, try to utilize the Event-Bus pattern as last resort.