# vue.js: Trigger binding update manually

Tags: javascript, data-binding, vue.js

I have a template calling a different component:

```
<question-container v-for="(question, index) in questions" :question="question" :answer="getFittingAnswer(question)"></question-container>
```

How can I update the `:answer` manually from the outer component? As `:answer` is dynamic based on data on a server and session data, in need the `getFittingAnswer` function.

Update: This is the `getFittingAnswer` component method.

```
getFittingAnswer(question) {
    return this[`part${question.part}answers`].find(a => a.questionId == question.Id)
}
```

Comment: Where is the getFittingAnswer? Is it a method from the parent component?

Comment: Yes it is - it works perfectly fine but kind of has to be "retriggered".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your case well. Can you provide a more complete code sample?

Comment: @Cobaltway Check the update.

Comment: Sorry I still do not get what the problem is. Is it a reactivity problem? What do you mean by "retriggered"? Maybe you can share the two components code (parent and child), possibly on a fiddle or code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `getFittingAnswer` method returns an object from my component data I simplified the template:

```
<question-container v-for="(question, index) in questions" :question="question" :value="part1answers.find(a => a.questionId == question.Id)"></question-container>
```

Using this directly, the data will always be up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

You can create global event bus for change time call this methods and listen this method and update answer 
[Vue.js global event bus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064054/vue-js-global-event-bus)